# Selected attribute in option tag

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that's populated through a loop. The selected attribute should be added when `<%if o.getNextPage()%>` is equal to `i`.

```html
<select id="dropDown" onchange="display(this.value)">

var start = 1;
var end = noOfPages;
var options = "";
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  options += "<option>" + i + "</option>";
}

document.getElementById("dropDown").innerHTML = options;


function display(e) {
  document.getElementById("hidden").value = e;
  document.invoiceForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Why inserting raw HTML when you could use ‘document.createElement‘ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `value` attribute to the `option` tag.

As suggested by @3Dos in comments you can use ‘document.createElement‘ without needing to insert raw HTML like this:

```
var start = 1;
var end = noOfPages;
var options = "";
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = i;
    opt.innerHTML = i;
    document.getElementById('dropDown').appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: i have removed the raw html code. on change of value in dropdown, i'm calling a javascript function that submits my form to the servlet. so the values in the dropdown is always selected as 1.

Comment: can you add a fiddle for your code. I can't help without seeing full code

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way of generating your dropdown list and preserve performance as you interact with the DOM only once thanks to the [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

```js
// These were not provided by OP but added to actually get this snippet running
var noOfPages = 5;

var start = 1;
var end = noOfPages;
var options = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = i;
  option.textContent = i;
  options.appendChild(option);
}

document.getElementById("dropDown").appendChild(options);
```

```html
<select id="dropDown" onchange="display(this.value)"></select>
```

I omitted the `display` function which is irrelevant as it refers to unprovided code.